# What are the min and max values draw from $N(0, \sigma^2)$ where $\sigma^2 = 2^{-25}$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Given

$$\sigma^2 = 2^{-25}, \mu=0$$

> The noise $e$ is sampled from a normal error distribution $\xi = N(0,
>  \sigma^2)$ over $\mathbb{R}_N$ [X]; namely, over polynomials of
> $\mathbb{R}_N[X]$ with coefficients drawn in $N(0, \sigma^2)$ where
> $\mathbb{R}_N[X] = \mathbb{R}[X]/(X^N+1)$.

How do I know the maximum and minimum coefficient values that can be picked following this distribution? Since I'm picking each coefficient from $\mathbb{R}$ following $N(0, 2^{-25})$, then can I just graph it somewhere and see the values?

Comment: Samples from the normal distribution are not bounded in probability, for each $b$ you can get a sample such that $P(|\xi| > b) > 0$. Of course, for your $\sigma$ this probability is practically $0$: you can use Chebyshev's inequality to get some probabilistic bounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal distribution has infinite support. So you could theoretically draw any value between $-\infty$ and $\infty$ from $N(0, 2^{-25})$. However, that variance is extremely small, so large values are exceedingly rare. One thing we can say for certain about any normal distribution $N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ is that 99.7% of its probability mass lies within $3\sigma$ from its mean. In your case, this means that 99.7% of your coefficients will be in the range $[-3 \cdot 2^{-25/2}, \; 3 \cdot 2^{-25/2}]$. Notice that, while we can't give any upper or lower bound with certainty, the resulting near-certain bound is very tight due to the extremely small variance.